# Are cookies set for .example.com available to all of the subdomains or only third level domains?

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I am setting a cookie for `.example.com`. I know that the cookie is sent with requests to `www.example.com` and `secure.example.com`, however will it be sent with requests to `server.www.example.com`? What about `long.sub.domain.name.for.example.com`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't see how the [manual](http://nz1.php.net/setcookie) cold be any clearer:

> The domain that the cookie is available to. Setting the domain to
>   'www.example.com' will make the cookie available in the www subdomain
>   and higher subdomains. Cookies available to a lower domain, such as
>   'example.com' will be available to higher subdomains, such as
>   'www.example.com'. Older browsers still implementing the deprecated »
>   RFC 2109 may require a leading . to match all subdomains.

and if you don't like the explanation, testing it would take less than 5 minutes

`one.two.three.example.com` is higher than `three.example.com`
both are subdomains of `example.com`

Comment: This is confusing: `...will make the cookie available in the www subdomain and higher subdomains...`, higher being `example.com` and `com`, while `Cookies available to a lower domain, such as 'example.com' will be available to higher subdomains, such as 'www.example.com'`, meaning `example.com` is lower domain and `www.example.com` is a higher domain. Which contradicts itself.

Comment: Testing is easy, when you have a server with control over subdomains and not when you are only planning on getting one..

Comment: you can test locally, and i really dont see a contradiction in the explanation. ok the usage of *higher* and *sub* are a little confusing